# jsf form should not submit on ajax event

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF form like this:

```
<h:form id="myform">
    <ui:repeat value="#{managedBean.getData()}" var="step">

        <h:outputText value="#{step.someValue}" />

        <h:commandLink id="link_to_events" onclick="openLoaderModalBase();" > 
        <f:ajax listener="#{managedBean.actionMethod(step.someValue)}"  render="link_to_events" />
        </h:commandLink>

    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

I would like to NOT submit the whole form when I click on my `commandLink`. If I click now on the link, my `managedBean.getData()` is invoked again, and it is take a while to be executed. I would like only invoke my `actionMethod` with the given paramter, and this method will redirect to another page.

I don't want to use PrimeFaces and I'm using JSF 2.2

Is this possible to do? Thank you!

Comment: Check the `f:ajax execute` attribute.

Comment: I tried, the same thing happens. The whole form is submiting.

Comment: I've tried this: <f:ajax listener="#{managedBean.actionMethod(step.someValue)}"  execute="link_to_events" />

Comment: I'm using JSF 2.2

Comment: What implementation of 2.2? Any JavaScript errors caused by `openLoaderModalBase()`?

Comment: there isn't any error, caused by openLoaderModalBase(), my modal is opening, and the redirection due to actionMethod happens, but I can se the log, my getData() method is invoked when i click on the commandlink.

Comment: i think my JSF implementation is Mojara

Comment: So, the `getData()` method is actually interacting with the DB instead of returning data which is already prepared during a `@ViewScoped` bean's construction? Why?

Comment: No, it’s not interacting with DB, but that method must iterate on two, sometimes three list. I’m using parallel stream but it’s a bit slow. :(

Comment: ok, no db access, but yhe rest of the comment by @BalusC is still valid. It should be done 'lazy'... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times

Comment: Ok, but, I think I cannot use here lazy loading. For example, my getData() is returning with a list. If i use if (this.someProperty == null) { ... code the property value will never refreshing.